# how to get the html document cookie string to System.net.Cookie using c# .net 3.5

Tags: c#, https, httprequest, session-cookies

I built a C# app using webbrower to automate saving financial activities on a particular site that uses https and sign on. Once user has manually signed on the app's webbrowser and navigate to the proper page for activities viewing, user can click a tool to save all activities under his control and optionally for a specific period or all periods.

the problem is the website do use cookies and will not allow opening another webbrowser;  seemed to refuse http request despite the correct url I constructed according to my observation using webbrowser

the non working code trying to save all activities for all available accounts:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public partial class Form1 :Form
{
    public Form1()
{
// ....... for simplicity and focus, I skip other code
and list only the relevant code that 'gets callled when use click the download all activity command tool
#region "prep dnlodActivity"
// get all available account number into sAccts
// and all period into activtyPeriod
// activtyPeriod[i,0] is used to set the url 
string ActvtyPeriodID = "ActivityPeriodID", jscrpt = "OnAccountChangeLocalActivity()",
   AcctDropdown;
string[,] sAccts, activtyPeriod;
HtmlElement heSelctdAcct = webBrowserDnLod.Document.GetElementById("hdnAccountsPage"),
   heAcctDropdown = webBrowserDnLod.Document.GetElementById("AcctDropdown"),
   heActivityPeriod = webBrowserDnLod.Document.GetElementById(ActvtyPeriodID),
   heGo = webBrowserDnLod.Document.GetElementById("cellGoButton"),
   heGoBtn = webBrowserDnLod.Document.GetElementById("AcctGoButton");
string acctInnerHtml = heAcctDropdown.InnerHtml,
   goHtml = heGo.InnerHtml;
   string sMsg, sActvtyRgx = @"<OPTION (selected ){0,1}value=(?<actvty>\w+)>(?<name>(\w| )+)<",
   sJscrptRgx = @"onclick=""javascript:(?<jscrpt>(\w|[()])+);";
Match m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(goHtml, sJscrptRgx, RegexParse4Lib.regexParse.roIcEc);
if (m.Success)
{
   jscrpt = m.Groups[1].ToString().Replace("()", "");   //ChangeActivityPeriod
}
if (!RegexParse4Lib.regexParse.findAllExplicit(acctInnerHtml,
   @"<OPTION (selected ){0,1}value=(?<acctID>\w+)>\w+ - (?<name>\w+( |\w|-)*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase,
   false, false, out sAccts, out sMsg))
{
   setStatus("failed to find account options- nothing saved for this session of Go autopilot");
   addMsg(sMsg);
   return;
}
if (!RegexParse4Lib.regexParse.findAllExplicit(heActivityPeriod.InnerHtml,//WebCtlDnLod.getAllText(),
   sActvtyRgx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, false, false, out activtyPeriod, out sMsg))
{
   setStatus("failed to find activity period options- nothing saved"); addMsg(sMsg);
   return;
}
#endregion "prep dnlodActivity"
// that was easy and no problem
string sBaseUrl = webBrowserDnLod.Url.ToString();
const string selAcctParm = "&&SelectedAccount=",
   AcctTypParm = "&SelectedAccountType";
int idxAcctTyp = sBaseUrl.IndexOf(AcctTypParm);
string sUrlTail = "&SelectedAccountType=RS-1&hdnAccountTypeStore=IN-1;RF-1;TF-1;RS-1;IN-2;IN-2;IN-2;TF-1;&hdnAccountsPage=&ActivityPeriod=";
if (idxAcctTyp > 0)
{
   sUrlTail = sBaseUrl.Substring(idxAcctTyp);
   sUrlTail = sUrlTail.Substring(0, sUrlTail.LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
   sBaseUrl = sBaseUrl.Substring(0, sBaseUrl.IndexOf(selAcctParm));
}
string activityAsOfDt = "", curAcct;
string actvtyPeriodHtml = heActivityPeriod.InnerHtml;
int idxPeriod;
foreach (string sAcct in sAccts)
{
   Util.Extract(actvtyPeriodHtml, @"value=(?<sel>\d{1,30})\sselected>", "${sel}", out activityAsOfDt);
   for (idxPeriod = 0; idxPeriod < activtyPeriod.GetLength(0); idxPeriod++)
   {
      if (activtyPeriod[idxPeriod, 0].Length != 8) continue;
      activityAsOfDt = activtyPeriod[idxPeriod, 0];
      string sUrl = sBaseUrl + selAcctParm + sAcct + "&BackupAccount=" + sAcct
      + sUrlTail + activityAsOfDt +"&";
      WebRequest wrGETURL;
      wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sUrl);
      wrGETURL.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy();
      Util.tryAddCookie(wrGETURL, webBrowserDnLod.Document.Cookie, webBrowserDnLod.Document.Domain) 
      Stream objStream;
      objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
      StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
      string sHtml = objReader.ReadToEnd();
      if (sLine.Contains("We cannot process your request"))
      { // always get executed:
         MessageBox.Show(sUrl + Util.CsCrlf + Util.CsCrlf + sHtml, "failed to login");
         return;
      }
      else // never gets here
      {
         MessageBox.Show(sHtml, "Great, got it");
         // call the extract and save code
         extractNSaveAllActivites(sHtml);
      }

   }
}
// I skip listing extractNSaveAllActivites as that is the the problem 
}

public static Class Util
{
      public static bool TryAddCookie(System.Net.WebRequest webRequest, string cookie, string domain)
    {
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest httpRequest = webRequest as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
        if (httpRequest == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (httpRequest.CookieContainer == null)
        {
            httpRequest.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        }

        System.Net.Cookie cookie2 = new System.Net.Cookie("somename", cookie);
        cookie2.Domain = domain;
        cookie2.Secure = true; //cookie2.Expired = false;
        cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(75);
        cookie2.Path = "Cookie:smith@www1.thebanksite.com/"

        httpRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookie2); // got flagged during runtime
/*
    System.ArgumentException was unhandled
    Message="The parameter '{0}' cannot be an empty string.\r\nParameter name: cookie.Domain"
    Source="System"
    ParamName="cookie.Domain"
    StackTrace:
       at System.Net.CookieContainer.Add(Cookie cookie)
    ...
*/
        return true;
    }
}
```

how can I get properly convert HtmlDocumemt cookie from the webbrowser to System.net.cookie? thx in advance, any hint or reference is very much appreciated.

my main job is system administration, some database administration with small side duties to enhance or add small apps. so excuse my weakness in c# .net esp in httprequest 
I've done a lot Google search but failed to find the proper key word to get the result.

I've also tried a different approach in webbrowser but I could not handle the complexities of stateful execution using webbrowser document completed event. Even if I succeed there, it would be nightmare to maintain.

Comment: I believe the code does not work because I don't know how to get the session context and cookie into http request from the webbrowser, hence the question title.

furthermore the use of proxy is irrelevant in this environment as taking it out produce the same error.

Comment: I've also tried setting cookie.Domain with the webbrowser.Document.domain However that led to the message of part of the cookie is invalid. Even after changing to:
    System.Net.Cookie cookie2 = new System.Net.Cookie("tehBankName", cookie);
    cookie2.Domain = domain;
    cookie2.Secure = true; //cookie2.Expired = false;
    cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(75);
    //cookie2.GetType()= ;//throw exception cookie2.Port
    cookie2.Path = "Cookie:smith@www1.thebank.com/";